# How to check if mongoDB connection is successful in C#

Tags: c#, mongodb

I want to check if my connection to mongoDB is successful? I have tried this code but it is not totally working (it is working just in the case of successful connection)

```
var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://name:pwd@ds***.mlab.com:port/db");
var db = client.GetDatabase("db");
var coll = db.GetCollection<Book>("book");

var server = client.GetServer();
server.Connect();


if(server.State.ToString() == "Connected")
{
            //do something
}
else
{
            //do something
}
```

EDIT:
I wanna do something like :

`if(server.isConnected){ 
    form2.show();} 
 else {
    console.write("error");}`

Comment: IIRC don't you get an exception? Just trap that. Of course that won't be raised until you actually perform an operation, getting something like a connection doesn't do anything by itself, try retrieving some stats or a raw  ping command.

Comment: How can i use ping ? what ping do exactly please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After creation of client try to get reference to your server and then call `Ping` function. This method by design throw exception if server isn't alive, so we can replace if-else block with try-catch:

```
 var server = client.GetServer();
 try {
   server.Ping();
   Console.WriteLine("Connected"); //or form2.show();
 }
 catch(ex)
 {
   Console.WriteLine("Failed");
 }
```

More details: [ping documentation](http://api.mongodb.com/csharp/1.8/html/4df96e2d-3273-1075-23df-6baea97942c3.htm)

Comment: i have tried it but it does nothing, it stop my app. i wanna something like : if(server.isConnected) { form2.show();} else {console.write("error")} thanks

Comment: I've added an edit for your case

Comment: thanks for your help but it's too slow to get the answer from the server in case of fail ?

Comment: Just an input. Client.GetServer() is no longer part of the Client.